# Cannot Deduce (simple) Typeclass from context

Tags: haskell

I'm getting an error in a pretty simple example and I'm unable to figure out what is wrong. What I'm doing is very similar to `mempty` in `Monoid`, here is a simple version (I include my quantified type in case that has something to do with the issue):

```
data Field a = Field String
              | forall b. EsMappable b => ReferenceField String (a -> b)

class EsMappable a where
    fields :: [Field a]

toMapping :: (EsMappable a) => a -> String
toMapping a = go "" fields
  where go str [] = str                        
        go str (ReferenceField name _ : xs) = go (name ++ str) xs
        go str (Field name : xs) =go (name ++ str) xs
```

The error I get is:

```
Could not deduce (EsMappable t0) arising from a use of ‘fields’
from the context (EsMappable a)
  bound by the type signature for
             toMapping :: EsMappable a => a -> String
  at search2.hs:11:14-42
The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
In the second argument of ‘go’, namely ‘fields’
In the expression: go "" fields
In an equation for ‘toMapping’:
    toMapping a
      = go "" fields
      where
          go str [] = str
          go str (ReferenceField name _ : xs) = go (name ++ str) xs
          go str (Field name : xs) = go (name ++ str) xs
```

**Note**: if I change the `EsMapapble` class to: `fields :: a -> [Field a]` and then in `toMapping` I change `go "" (fields a)`, it works.

**My Question**: why am I getting this error? Is this not the same as `mempty`? What is preventing GHC from properly resolving `fields`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler has no way to link your use of `fields` to your argument `a`. Your `go` function can take in a `[Field a]` for *any* `a`, so you need to somehow specifically constrain it to be the same as the `a` in your argument type.

You can do this nicely with `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
toMapping :: forall a. (EsMappable a) => a -> String
toMapping _ = go "" (fields :: [Field a])
```

You need the extra `forall a` to explicitly make the `a` type variable scoped. This is a restriction on `ScopedTypeVariables` in the interest of backwards compatibility.

This would also not have been a problem if you had used your `a` argument with the `Field a` values in `go`. As a contrived example, the following typechecks without the explicit signature:

```
go str (ReferenceField name f : xs) = go (name ++ str) xs `const` f a
```

This forces `f` to take an argument of type `a`, which constrains the whole list to that specific `a`. So you could actually use this trick to avoid the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension if you really wanted to! I wouldn't suggest that though: the extension is about as harmless as they come and makes the code much clearer. This example was just for illustrating my point.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I see now what the subtley is. Additionally, seeing your example using `const` to constrain `a` was really helpful and also a great, albeit hacky, example of where laziness is kind of useful!